# can't import foo.sql

Tags: postgresql

I have the `foo.sql` file with following contents:

```
-- ...
COPY service_types (id, name, created_at, updated_at, metadata, "primary") FROM stdin;
26  AWS Other       2014-11-18 10:28:30.642037  2014-11-18 10:28:30.642037      f
27  AWS Marketplace 2014-11-18 10:34:40.87182   2014-11-18 10:34:40.87182       f
3   AWS EC2         2014-11-06 11:04:30.877178  2014-11-06 11:04:30.877178      f
\.
-- ...
```

When I try to import it with

```
psql -h localhost -d database -U user -f foo.sql
```

I get the following errors:

```
psql:20150807_service_types.sql:48: invalid command \.
psql:20150807_service_types.sql:55: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "26"
LINE 1: 26 AWS Other 2014-11-18 10:28:30.642037 2014-11-18 10:28:30....
```

Can anyone see the root of the problem?

Comment: i think this is answered here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41039/usage-of-copy-from-stdin-in-postgres

Comment: Have you tried with psql < foo.sql?

Comment: @kometen yeap, i have

Comment: Different postgresql versions?